# How to display a random rows frame with Dojo tools

Tags: html, dojo

[image: enter image description]

I just want get a Dojo frame like the images .

I know how to set the testdata (JSON) . but i do not know how to write a Dojo widget or Dojo frame like this. I mean how to write the HTML file to this style

Comment: It looks like this can be achieved by using dgrid components, by using its  List or OnDemandList and styling the CSS a little bit. It shouldn't be too complicated to code that. I highlt suggest taking a look on the dgrid documentaation: http://dgrid.io/

Comment: Thank you .  But I want to use Dojo widget to do this.  do you have any idea ?